# Getting Camel error with RestBindingMode.auto

Tags: spring-boot, rest, maven, apache-camel

I'm getting error when running springboot Camel with maven on next line `.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)`.

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable RestBindingMode
  location: class com.example.MySpringBootRouter
```

Am I missing some dependency?
I think that shouldn't be a problem because I have next dependecies in my `pom.xml` and I don't know why I'm getting this error.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-camel-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Spring Boot Route</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.boot-version>2.3.0.RELEASE</spring.boot-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Spring Boot BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-stream-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JMS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jms-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- REST -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-rest-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
     </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-netty-http-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
         <artifactId>camel-jetty-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

MySpringBootRouter.java

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * A simple Camel route that triggers from a timer and calls a bean and prints to system out.
 * <p/>
 * Use <tt>@Component</tt> to make Camel auto detect this route when starting.
 */
@Component
public class MySpringBootRouter extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
    public void configure() {

    String listenAddress = "192.168.0.50";
    int listenPort = 8161;

        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                //.component("jetty")
                //.component("netty-http")
                .scheme("http")
                .host(listenAddress)
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                .port(listenPort);

        rest("/artemis-rest/queues/test")
                .post()
                .produces("application/json")
                .to("direct:route1");
                
        from("direct:route1")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("Boo!");
   }

}
```

If I comment `//.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)` Camel starts OK.

Comment: Looking at the class you posted, you are missing to import 

    org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode

Comment: Thank you. That solved problem with `.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luca said, I forgot to import RestBindingMode in MySpringBootRouter.java.

`import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode`